# How to have multiple IP address mapped to a single server's files

Tags: linux, dns, ip, server-response, server-monitoring

I have a dedicated linux hosting machine from godaddy. I also have purchased two website domains. Say it is abc.com and xyz.com.

xyz.com is already setup to the server.

I want to get abc.com's traffic to a subfolder of xyz.com but the links must remain as abc.com. i.e abc.com/index.html must be in xyz.com/abc/index.html path. But xyz.com/abc/index.html must return a 404 while abc.com/index.html must return the proper page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `apache` with `mod_proxy` enabled, configuring a `ReverseProxy` will do the job. This is an example of the directives to add in `abc.com` domain's apache configuration:

```
 ProxyPass / http://xyz.com/subfoder
 ProxyPassReverse / http://xyz.com/subfolder
```

These will forward all requests to http://xyz.com/subfoder`

Also have a look to [apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)